# Performance difference between SQL Server Standard & Enterprise Edition 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is there really a performance difference between Standard & Enterprise Edition 2005 if I am not using any of the Enterprise Features ?

Answer (score 6):

The Enterprise edition has a few things that Standard doesn't have:

- support for more than 4 CPU's
- partitioning
- parallel index operations
- indexed views

So if your apps would make use of those features, then yes - there can be a performance difference. But if you only manage a couple hundred items in a table - no difference....

See here for a [complete feature comparison](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compare-features.aspx)

Comment: You can have indexed views in standard edition. What Enterprise adds is that it will consider using such indexes for queries against the base tables. To benefit from the index in Standard edition, you have to be querying the view itself, and use the NOEXPAND hint.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not in your case - since you know you're not using the Enterprise features.

Key performance difference affecting features would be indexed views (an optimization consideration), number of processors (need more than 4?), and table partitioning (can give performance boost, but primary purpose is not performance, but management - also an execution plan bug in 2005 which results in some partitioned table plans to be slower than non-partitioned table plans)

Comment: How about features that are not explicitly used by us, like Advanced Scanning and Larger Read Ahead Buffering on SAN and Large Page Extensions? Refer to this link http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/merry-go-round-scans/  , how much difference does this make or is there any at all?

Comment: @nevhirion We would need to know more about your system.  Typically, like most things, until your system attains a certain size (100s of GB) and load (thousands of requests a minute), you won't need to worry much about these things.  Like most databases, if you are going to base your system on SQL Server, you should understand how you expect to use it first and then look at what the best practices are for that particular platform, given your expected usage patterns.  Even the Express edition can handle significant implementations.

Comment: @Cade Roux: thanks for replying. I understand each SQL Server setup is different and will require tuning based on our requirements. Our system (only 20 GB!) has slowed down recently and there is pressure from management to upgrade to the Enterprise Edition. I am advocating to tune the queries and trying to prove that there should not be any significant performance difference between Std and Enterprise Edition.

Comment: @nevhirion You would almost certainly be wasting money on Enterprise Edition.  I would recommend you engage an experienced SQL Server DBA to use the profiler and other tools on your system to identify the root causes of the performance issues.

Comment: @Cade Roux Thanks for the input. I have also suggested to engage an experienced SQL Server DBA to help diagnose our slowness, but budget is an issue. Will have to try and take on the challenge myself. Wish me luck!

Comment: @nevhirion Building the expertise in-house is a good idea.  If budget is an issue, you may really need to rethink the feasibility of the project.  Very few database systems are tuning-free, and while SQL Server is very powerful, there are no systems that scale indefinitely simply without some deeper expertise.  You will either invest in staff, training, software, hardware or get lower performance.